# Fire + Smoke disappears

Tags: fire

I am creating a presentation for a conference on cancer radiation therapy. This includes a 15 second animation of a linac machine.

I'm trying to show a helix of smoke created by the machine spinning around the patient (That's the best idea I had sorry). But there is just no way I can keep the fire going. It disappears after frame 90.

I would appreciate any advice. Thanks. I have to attach the file because I have tried for a long time without success.

[image]

In the end I would like to show a helix of smoke (or any other material) with something like 8 or 10 loops. Right now I'm only getting two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your emitter exits the domain after that frame. Enlarge the domain to encompass the full animation of your emitter. Also, you should set sampling subframes on the emitter to stop it from making that dotty effect. It will sample the motion in between frames. The emitter is moving too fast to produce a smooth stream of smoke.

Comment: So that was the problem.

The dotty effect was actually what I intended to do. No problems there.